# How to extract image and introduction from url

Tags: reactjs, node.js

I have one problem to extract image and introduction letters from URL.
For example, when type and submit some urls in telegram or skype, it shows an image and letters. So, if we click the image, it redirect to the url.
For example, when I type and submit "tailwindcss.com", it shows tailwind css image and some letters.
How can I display it using MERN stack or some stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [open-graph-scrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open-graph-scraper) for that.

From their documentation:

```
const ogs = require('open-graph-scraper');
const options = { url: 'http://ogp.me/' };
ogs(options)
  .then((data) => {
    const { error, html, result, response } = data;
    console.log('error:', error);  // This returns true or false. True if there was an error. The error itself is inside the result object.
    console.log('html:', html); // This contains the HTML of page
    console.log('result:', result); // This contains all of the Open Graph results
    console.log('response:', response); // This contains response from the Fetch API
  })
```

Sample result:

```
{
  ogTitle: 'Open Graph protocol',
  ogType: 'website',
  ogUrl: 'https://ogp.me/',
  ogDescription: 'The Open Graph protocol enables any web page to become a rich object in a social graph.',
  ogImage: [
    {
      height: '300',
      type: 'image/png',
      url: 'https://ogp.me/logo.png',
      width: '300'
    }
  ],
  charset: 'utf-8',
  requestUrl: 'http://ogp.me/',
  success: true
}
```